# Nested Angular add schematics

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I have a project Child that has an add schematic.  If Child becomes a dependency of a project Parent which also has an add schematic, how would ng-cli handle this?  I don't see any references to `ng add` cascading or calling through to dependency schemas.  Would Parent need to replicate Child's schematic, or is there a way to manually call through to Child's schematic in the Parent schematic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really wish the documentation was better, but the solution ended up being a combination of two things:

First you can call an external schematic like so:

`externalSchematic('@keysight/alloy', 'ng-add', options)`

However, that alone is not enough since it won't be able to find your package.  You'll need to install it first.  Here's the final solution:

```
export function ngAdd(options: any): Rule {
  return (tree: Tree, context: SchematicContext) => {
    console.log('Adding Pathwave Core dependencies...\n');
    dependencies.forEach(dep => addPackageJsonDependency(tree, dep));
    const installTaskId = context.addTask(new NodePackageInstallTask());

    // Chain won't work here since we need the externals to be actually installed before we call their schemas
    // This ensures the externals are a dependency of the node install, so they exist when their schemas run.
    context.addTask(new RunSchematicTask('addExternals', options), [installTaskId]);
  };
}

export function addExternals(options: any): Rule {
  return (_tree: Tree, _context: SchematicContext) => {
    console.log('Running dependency schematics...\n');
    return chain([
      externalSchematic('@keysight/alloy', 'ng-add', options)
    ]);
  };
}
```

`addExternals` must be its own schematic in `collection.json`:

```
    "addExternals": {
      "description": "Calls dependency add schemas",
      "private": true,
      "factory": "./ng-add/index#addExternals"
    }
```